# Getting undefined reference errors when trying to compile android kernel

Tags: c, compiler-errors, kernel

Im trying to compile an android kernel, but shortly after running make -j4 it spits out an error.

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `cs_check_cpu':
/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_relaxed.c:67: undefined reference to `state_suspended'
/home/jack/Downloads/GCCToolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: drivers/built-in.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external symbol `state_suspended' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_relaxed.c:67: undefined reference to `state_suspended'
block/built-in.o: In function `maple_add_request':
/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/block/maple-iosched.c:81: undefined reference to `state_suspended'
/home/jack/Downloads/GCCToolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: block/built-in.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external symbol `state_suspended' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/block/maple-iosched.c:81: undefined reference to `state_suspended'
block/built-in.o: In function `maple_dispatch_requests':
/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/block/maple-iosched.c:209: undefined reference to `state_suspended'
/home/jack/Downloads/GCCToolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: block/built-in.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against external symbol `state_suspended' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
block/built-in.o:/home/jack/Downloads/NethunterKernel/block/maple-iosched.c:209: more undefined references to `state_suspended' follow
make: *** [Makefile:995: vmlinux] Error 1
```

Im pretty sure state_suspended is declared in include/linux/state_notifier.h with

> extern bool state_suspended;

state_notifier.h is included in all the files it complains about though. Could anyone help?

This is the kernel im trying to compile: https://github.com/Svirusx/Nethunter-s7-kernel-WirusMOD-AiO

Comment: how many cores do you have?

Comment: The line `extern bool state_suspended;` only **declares** the variable. But the error message is about not **defined** variable.

Comment: I see Tsyvarev, but then how do i know what to ddefine it as